# 94 Camry Le shut off going down the road; cranks only after cooled, then shuts off again

Tags: toyota, camry

The car cut off when going down the road. It would not would not crank until after about 30 minutes. Than it ran for 10 minutes and cut off again. Can anyone suggest what may be wrong

Comment: When you say "would not crank until after about 30 minutes" ... do you mean when you turn the key, nothing happens? Or do you mean that you can turn the key, the engine will crank over and over, but the engine won't fire?